# Can not remove max user connections

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL, and not sure if i'm doing something wrong or is the database limited by the host company.

Every time i try to use one of the recomanded solutions that i was able to find, i get an error.

[image: error]

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO overlim1_bot_acc@localhost WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;`

What should/can i do?
Should i upgrade to a bigger host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the user which you are currently connected does not have GRANT privilage,

You need to use elevated user such as root, in order to grant other user for anything.

Comment: Not sure how exactly to do/find that. As i've said i'm fairly new to SQL, and just logging in from the website's Cpanel (that came with the host).

Comment: if you are using CPanel you cannot do what you are trying. It is limited by your host. If you need something talk with your host

Comment: I'll contact the hosting company, thank you for your time and happy new year!